# Behat / Mink / Selenium: intercepting AJAX calls possible?

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I am using Behat/Mink with Selenium for acceptance testing. I need to determine if my web page is making a badly formed call to the server via Ajax. The problem is, the server will attempt to "correct" badly-formed code and return valid data nonetheless.

Is there a way to "intercept" and validate ajax calls made from my website?

Right now my FeatureContext class looks like:

```
public function performAnAction()
{
  $this->enterInField('test', 'field');
  $this->hitOKButton();
  $this->assertResponseContains('success');
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
public function performAnAction()
{
  $this->enterInField('test', 'field');
  $this->hitOKButton();
  $ajax = $this->getAllAjaxCalls();
  foreach ($ajax as $call) {
    // perform some validation
  }
  $this->assertResponseContains('success');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two great resources for doing checks on ajax calls

The behat mink way

http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html#defining-our-own-featurecontext

This is a neat solution using _before and _after overrides to getting deeper inside the base functionality and is very interesting but reading through it will help you get a better understanding of what the framework is really doing under the covers

http://blog.scur.pl/2012/06/ajax-callback-support-behat-mink/

I think you could simply use the built in wait function with the js callback to get what you want in your custom step def by putting your response into a jquery data[] object on any html element and verify your expected output that way.

```
$this->getSession()->wait(5000,
        "$('.someCssClassSelectorToElementWithResponseStuff').length > 0"
    );
```

If your element were a js object that would work
Or if it comes back as a jquery object you could use .size() instead of length
just make sure your injected js evaluates to true of false to get your pass/fail